# Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) using mysql in Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, error-handling, breakpoints

I am creating a Spring Boot application using the mysql database dependency however I am getting the error:
`java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

I have included my pom.xml and application.properties files below:

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/AssignmentSubApp_DB
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password= password123

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

The above are my application.properties settings that I have selected are above, and I am not too sure if these are the reasons for the error. I have tried changing, however, the error remained.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.AssignmentApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>AssignmentSubmission</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>AssignmentSubmission</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: There is a blank space in front of your PW. I'm not sure if this cause your trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to remove  all the spaces found in the password and user in the `application.properties` file since based on my thinking Spring Boot thinks the spaces is a character in the password or username.

To be sure I would recommend rewriting the password and username.